# Prevent escape_string slashes from being printed

Tags: php, database, mysqli, server-side

I've written a blog system which works quite well, except for one little thing. I'm using a `mysqli::real_escape_string` to prevent the system from being exposed to SQL-injections. However, if someone writes a comment with a " or ' in it, these will be shown as \" or \', which isn't exactly user friendly.

Is there a way to prevent these from being written, or removing them before being echoed with PHP?

Comment: Are you sure PHP echoes the escapes when you retrieve the data from MySQL? It might look like that in your database, but I've never had a problem with them rendering when querying with PHP.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Show the relevant code.

Comment: need to see your full code

Comment: Are you, by any chance, escaping values then using them in prepared statements? If so, don't do it, you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, escaping happen twice (probably because of the enabled settings "magic_quotes_gpc=On")

Example:

```
Is your name O'reilly?
```

When this parameter transmission browser (client) -> php (web-server) with magic_quotes_gpc = on

```
Is your name O\'reilly?
```

Then your code mysqli_real_escape_string

```
Is your name O\\\'reilly?
```

The result is stored in the table:

```
Is your name O\'reilly?
```

Сonclusion:

Outdated setting «magic_quotes_gpc» to disable.

NOTE. *To prevent SQL-injection when the sql query is more expedient to use [«prepared statements»](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in this case, the parameters do not require escaping.*